# When exactly do you need to import in java?

Tags: class, methods, import, java-7

The following unexpectedly compiled and ran without a problem:

```
import info.gridworld.actor.Actor;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ChameleonKid extends ChameleonCritter
{
    public ArrayList<Actor> getActors()
    {
        ArrayList<Actor> actors = getGrid().getNeighbors(getLocation());
          ArrayList<Actor> frontBack = new ArrayList<Actor>();
          for(Actor i : actors)
              if(getLocation().getDirectionToward(i.getLocation())==getDirection())
                    frontBack.add(i);
        return frontBack;
    }
}
```

The method getLocation() in the Actor class returns an instance of Location. And then I call the getDirectionToward() method of the Location class. `getLocation().getDirectionToward(i.getLocation())`. How does this work? I never imported the Location class. How am I able to work with it and call its methods? If that is how it works, when would I *need* to import a class? Only if I am instantiating it?

I am using Java 7.

Comment: Yes indeed. I don't really need this to finish the problem but I was just wondering about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have two methods, one returning `foo.Location` and the other returning `bar.Location` (two completely different classes happening to have the same name, but in different packages - completely valid):

```
foo.Location getFooLocation();
bar.Location getBarLocation();
```

When you can both of these methods in the same class and chain some methods, you don't need an import:

```
if(getFooLocation().onlyInFoo()) {
  //...
}
if(getBarLocation().onlyInBar()) {
  //...
}
```

It works because the compiler is completely sure which version (from which package) of `Location` are you using and it knows where `onlyInFoo()` and `onlyInBar` are available.

But suppose you need a local variable:

```
Location location;
// much later
location = getFooLocation();
```

Now the compiler doesn't really know `Location` do you mean, so you must help him either by proceeding class name with package:

```
foo.Location location;
```

or by importing that class:

```
import foo.Location;
```

You should now ask: *what if I want to have local variable of both `foo.Location` and `bar.Location`*? Well, you can't import them both, obviously:

```
//WRONG
import foo.Location;
import bar.Location;
```

What you can do is again: either don't import at all and use fully qualified names:

```
foo.Location location1;
bar.Location location;
```

...or import just one location:

```
import foo.Location;

//...
Location location1;     //foo.Location
bar.Location location2;
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you don't need to import that class is because of the fact that you are not explicitly using that class. `Actor` is the one *actually* using the `Location` class locally. You are never holding a reference to the Location class and so, you are able to keep using it dynamically. However, if you wanted to hold a reference (eg `Location l = getLocation();`), you would have to import `Location` since the compiler has to link `l` with Location, but has no idea where to find it.